# check if file is a c file and compile it

Tags: c, file, compilation, operating-system, system-calls

I want to run recursively over a directory and its files and sub-directories. let's say that the directory can contain any king of file(c,txt,python....)  check if the current file is a c file and compile it if it is.
here is what i have so far:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<errno.h> 

void listdir(const char *name, int indent)
 {
  DIR *dir;
   struct dirent *entry;

if (!(dir = opendir(name)))
    return;

while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
    if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR) {
        char path[1024];
        if (strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") == 0)
            continue;
        snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "%s/%s", name, entry->d_name);
        printf("%*s[%s]\n", indent, "", entry->d_name);
        listdir(path, indent + 2);
    } else {
        printf("%*s- %s\n", indent, "", entry->d_name);
    }
}
closedir(dir);
}

int main(void) {
listdir(".", 0);
return 0;
}
```

how can I check if a file is a c file? and how to I compile it using the code?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: check the file extension should be okay. Then run `system("gcc -c ")` on the file

Comment: OT:  for ease of readability and understanding:  consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces

Comment: when calling `gcc`, always enable the warnings.  for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-c -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is very likely mis-guided (you may have an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)): compiling `C` is rarely the trivial matter of running a compiler over it: you will likely need to know what `-I` and `-D` (and other) flags it need to be compiled with, what libraries need to be linked in, etc. etc.

> how can I check if a file is a c file? and how to I compile it using the code?

You can run `system("gcc -c $file.c")` and if it compiles (`system` returns 0), it likely was a `C` file.

Note: if the file *doesn't* compile, it may be because it's not a `C` file, or because you didn't pass the right flags to the compiler.

> how do I make it run my current file?

Something like this:

```
char path[PATH_MAX];
char cmd[4096 + 2*PATH_MAX];

snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "%s/%s", name, entry->d_name); 
snprintf(cmd, sizeof(cmd), "gcc -c %s -o %s.o", path, path);
if (system(cmd) == 0) {
  printf("Compiled %s to %s.o\n", path, path);
}
```

Comment: so lets say my program is checking the current file and I want to run system("gcc -c $file.c")  how do I make it run my current file? is system("gcc -c $ entry->d_name") would work?